# Subquery returning field from second table with between operator using value from first table

Tags: postgresql, subquery, between

I have a problem with doing a subquery in PostgreSQL to get a calculated column value, it reports:

> [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

### Situation

I have two tables:

1. accounts
2. postal_code_to_state

Accounts table (subset of columns)

| name | postal_code | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cust One | 00020 | NULL |
| Cust Two | 63076 | CD |

Postal Code to State

| pc_from | pc_to | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 30 | AB |
| 63000 | 63100 | CD |

The `accounts` table has rows where the state value *may* be unknown, but there is a postal code value. The postal code field is char (but that is incidental).

The `postal_code_to_state` table has rows with postcode (integer) from & to columns. That is the low/high numbers of the postal code range for a state.

There is no common field to do joins. To get the state from the `postal_code_to_state` table the char field is cast to INT and the `between` operator used, e.g.

```
SELECT state
FROM postal_code_to_state
WHERE CAST('00020' AS INT) BETWEEN pc_from AND pc_to
```

this works OK, there is also a unique index on `pc_from` and `pc_to`.

But I need to run a query selecting from the accounts table and populating the state column from the state column ***in the postal_code_to_state table*** using the postal_code from the accounts table to select the appropriate row.

I can't figure out why PostgreSQL is complaining about the subquery returning multiple rows. This is the query I am currently using:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       postal_code,
       state,
       (SELECT state
        FROM postal_code_to_state
        WHERE CAST(accounts.postal_code AS INT) BETWEEN pc_from AND pc_to) AS new_state
FROM accounts
WHERE postal_code IS NOT NULL ;
```

If I use `LIMIT 1` in the subquery it is OK, and it returns the correct state value from postal_code_to_state, but would like to have it working without need to do that.

### UPDATE 2022-10-22

@Adrian - thanks for query to find duplicates, I had to change your query a little, the `!= 'empty'` to `!= FALSE`.

When I run it on data I get this, groups of two rows (1 & 2, 3 & 4, etc.) shows the overlapping ranges.

| state | pc_from | pc_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA | 9010 | 9134 |
| OR | 9070 | 9170 |
| UD | 33010 | 33100 |
| PN | 33070 | 33170 |
| TS | 34010 | 34149 |
| GO | 34070 | 34170 |
| CB | 86010 | 86100 |
| IS | 86070 | 86170 |

So if I run...

```
SELECT pc_from,
       pc_to,
       state
FROM postal_code_to_state
WHERE int4range(pc_from, pc_to) @> 9070;
```

I get...

| pc_from | pc_to | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9010 | 9134 | CA |
| 9070 | 9170 | OR |

So, from the PostgreSQL side, the problem is clear - obviously it is the data. On the point of the data, what is shown on a site that has Italian ZIP code information is interesting:

https://zip-codes.nonsolocap.it/cap?k=12071&b=&c=

This was one of the dupes I had already removed.

The exact same ZIP code is used in two completely different provinces (states) - go figure! Given that the ZIP code is meant to resolve down to the street level, I can't see how one code can be valid for two localities.

Comment: I'm going to say there are overlapping `pc_from` and `pc_to` values so you are picking up more then one state at a time. In other words two or more states have postcode ranges that share values.

Comment: Hi - the two postcode columns have a combined unique index so there is no possibility of duplicate rows of, say, 100 & 200, for the pc_to and pc_from columns. 

Only thing that could be possible (which I will double check) is that there are different rows but which have duplicate values within the range.

Comment: Try: `select a_tbl.state, a_tbl.pc_from, a_tbl.pc_to from postal_code_to_state as a_tbl, (select *  from postal_code_to_state) as b_tbl where a_tbl.state != b_tbl.state and int4range(a_tbl.pc_from, a_tbl.pc_to, '[]') * int4range(b_tbl.pc_from, b_tbl.pc_to, '[]') != 'empty';`

Comment: If, as I suspect there are overlapping ranges I would look at [Range indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING).

Comment: Addresses are tricky things: http://www.grcdi.nl/pidm/postal%20code.html

Comment: Yes... and companies (as well as governments) having reasonably clean postcode databases want to charge a fortune for them.

But regardless, one would sort of expect that the same postcode didn't point to two different states - like I have found... oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query to find duplicates:

```
select 
    a_tbl.state, a_tbl.pc_from, a_tbl.pc_to 
from 
    postal_code_to_state as a_tbl, 
   (select *  from postal_code_to_state) as b_tbl 
where 
    a_tbl.state != b_tbl.state 
and 
   int4range(a_tbl.pc_from, a_tbl.pc_to, '[]') && int4range(b_tbl.pc_from, b_tbl.pc_to, '[]') != 'empty';
```

If there are duplicates, after clearing them then you can do:

```
alter table 
    postal_code_to_state 
add 
   constraint exclude_test EXCLUDE USING GIST  (int4range(pc_from, pc_to, '[]') WITH &&);
```

This will set up an exclusion constraint to prevent overlapping ranges.

So:

```
insert into postal_code_to_state values (10, 30, 'AB'), (6300, 63100, 'CD');
insert into postal_code_to_state values (25, 40, 'SK');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "exclude_test"

insert into postal_code_to_state values (31, 40, 'SK');
INSERT 0 1

select * from postal_code_to_state ;
 pc_from | pc_to | state 
---------+-------+-------
      10 |    30 | AB
   63000 | 63100 | CD
      31 |    40 | SK
```

Answer (score 0):

The combined unique index would not protect you against overlapping postal codes, only duplicates. First, I'd write the query like this

```
SELECT id, name, postcode, coalesce(accounts.state, postal_code_to_state.state) state
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN postal_code_to_state ON accounts.postal_code::Integer BETWEEN pc_from AND pc_to
WHERE accounts.state IS NOT NULL OR postal_code_to_state.state IS NOT NULL;
```

You could modify it to tell you which are overlapping

```
SELECT id, coalesce(accounts.state, postal_code_to_state.state) state
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN postal_code_to_state ON accounts.postal_code::Integer BETWEEN pc_from AND pc_to
WHERE accounts.state IS NOT NULL OR postal_code_to_state.state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id,state
HAVING count(id) > 1;
```

I haven't tested any of this.

Comment: user:7070613 I indeed did find duplicate ranges within two pc_from & pc_to rows, thanks. I got this data from a website of Italian postal codes and copied into a table. I will have to go through it and clear it of overlaps. I didn't see your reply as an answer so I couldn't mark your response as answer.

Deepstop - thanks I will test your query as way of finding overlapping data in rows.

Adrian if you don't mind I will mark Deepstop's reply as answer as you were both on the right track and it will be good to show the question answered

Comment: Adrian, sorry got the at notice wrong.